# Can't make bitmap out of image without absolute URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bitmap

I have an application but I realised that it's not very smart to use absolute URLS for load images in a bitmap.

This is my piece of code:

```
var searchingBitmap = new Bitmap(@"c:\images\searching.png");
```

Now I want to include the files in my project (I did that by adding new files in a "images" map in my solution.

But how can I refactor that absolute url to the images folder in my project images folder?

This doesnt work:

```
var searchingBitmap = new Bitmap(@"images\searching.png");
```

Comment: Is this asp.net or winforms or wpf or?

Comment: Its using the .NET Framework 4.5 as the Target Famework and the Windows Application as Output type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple! Just look at this example:

```
string relativePath = @"images\searching.png";
string absolutePath1 = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);

// Warning! Doesn't work with '..\images\searching.png'
string absolutePath2 = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, relativePath);
```